# Bash: capture the remaining lines after a fixed amount of lines

Tags: bash

I have a text file with lines in a set order. I need to ignore the first 7 lines and grab whatever is left (if anything), for example:

```
Tuesday 22 July  10:50:29 EST 2014
Tuesday 22 July  10:50:32 EST 2014
Tuesday 22 July  10:50:32 EST 2014
Tuesday 22 July  10:50:33 EST 2014
Tuesday 22 July  10:50:38 EST 2014
Tuesday 22 July  10:50:40 EST 2014
Tuesday 22 July  10:50:45 EST 2014
Tuesday 22 July  10:50:47 EST 2014 <- I want this line and beyond
Tuesday 22 July  10:50:52 EST 2014
```

However if there is 7 lines or less I don't want to receive any lines.

I've been playing around with various combinations of `head` and `tail` but I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ tail -n +3 <<< $'1\n2\n3\n4\n5'
3
4
5
```

So:

```
tail -n +8
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sed 1,7d input-file
```

....................